# Why (in "cluster" mode) is my UDF executed locally (in driver) instead on worker(s)

Tags: java, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Two spark workers are running, the code is as follows (JUnit :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.ImmutablePair;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.RowFactory;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataTypes;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructField;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class UdfTest {

    @Test
    public void simpleUdf() {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
                .set("spark.driver.host", "localhost")
                .setMaster("spark://host1:7077")
                .set("spark.jars", "/home/.../myjar.jar")
                .set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster")
                .setAppName("RESTWS ML");

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate();

        List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            rows.add(RowFactory.create("cr" + i));
        }

        Dataset<Row> textAsDataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rows,
            new StructType(new StructField[] { new StructField("contentRepositoryUUID", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()) }));

        sparkSession.udf().register("myUdf",
            (UDF1<String, String>)(col1) -> myUdf(col1), DataTypes.StringType);

        Dataset<Row> rowDataset = textAsDataset.withColumn("text", functions.callUDF("myUdf",
            textAsDataset.col("contentRepositoryUUID")
        ));
        rowDataset.show();
    }

    private String myUdf(String col1) {
        new Exception().printStackTrace();
        return col1 + " changed";
    }
}
```

A dataset is created and I expect the java function `myUdf()` to be called from the worker java processes, but it is called from the driver thread instead, the stacktrace originates from the `rowDataset.show()` line:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at UdfTest.myUdf(UdfTest.java:53)
    at UdfTest.lambda$simpleUdf$45ca9450$1(UdfTest.java:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration$$anonfun$259.apply(UDFRegistration.scala:759)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF$$anonfun$2.apply(ScalaUDF.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.ScalaUDF.eval(ScalaUDF.scala:1063)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.Alias.eval(namedExpressions.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.InterpretedMutableProjection.apply(Projection.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$24$$anonfun$applyOrElse$23.apply(Optimizer.scala:1364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$24$$anonfun$applyOrElse$23.apply(Optimizer.scala:1364)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$24.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1364)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$$anonfun$apply$24.applyOrElse(Optimizer.scala:1359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$2.apply(TreeNode.scala:259)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformDown$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$4.apply(TreeNode.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapProductIterator(TreeNode.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$class.transformDown(AnalysisHelper.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDown(LogicalPlan.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transform(TreeNode.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1358)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldl(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:66)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foldLeft(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
    at UdfTest.simpleUdf(UdfTest.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:571)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:707)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:979)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1116)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1028)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:996)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:110)
```

How does Spark decide if the UDF can be called from workers?

The strange thing is, that it already worked once but now as I tried to reproduce this "distributed UDF" scenario something has changed so that I cannot. Looking at Spark DEBUG logs didn't help me unfortunately.

Comment: How do you get `myUDF` to trigger when it is not part of the lineage of `textAsDataset`? Perhaps the last line should be `tokens.show()` and also the argument to `tokenizer.transform()` should be `rowDataset` and not `textAsDataset`?

Comment: Sorry & thanks @HristoIliev for your finding. I gathered the code fragments which resulted in incorrect variable names. The UDF is triggered in the end, but "locally", in the driver.

Comment: Could you please post the full stack trace? I'm still a bit sceptical.

Comment: Okay I did my homework :) Providing a JUnit test. Hope this is a silly configuration or my misunderstanding of Spark...

Comment: What is your deployment scenario? You load this code in a project in IntelliJ and run the tests locally or submit via `spark-submit`?

Comment: @HristoIliev: I execute the test from IntelliJ. This is also the deployment scenario I thought to use in the production. Spawning ```spark-submit``` every time would IMO make task management and synchronization more complicated. I want to build machine learning models, save and execute them from the server JVM by using the Spark session and distributing the load to several workers OR alternatively doing this in "local" mode for smaller scenarios.

Comment: I did a bit of experimentation on my system, trying to replicate your case as closely as possible. It has something to do with how and when Spark distributes the RDD blocks. Replacing `textAsDataset.withColumn(...)` with `textAsDataset.repartition(1).withColumn(...)` actually pushes the block to the executor and you'll see the stack trace based off a completely different location.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the stack trace indeed originates from the `show()` call, the key is acutally...

```
...
HERE --> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:72)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.sparkPlan(QueryExecution.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:77)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:77)
...
at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
...
```

You are still in the query optimisation phase, which is done by Catalyst in the driver.

The reason for this is a poorly documented peculiarity of Spark, namely that datasets created from local collections using `SparkSession.createDataFrame()` (`SparkSession.createDatset()`/`Seq.toDF()` in Scala) are merely local relations inside the driver and not really distributed:

```
scala> val df = (0 to 5).toDF
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df.queryExecution.analyzed
res45: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
LocalRelation [value#107]

scala> df.isLocal
res46: Boolean = true
```

unlike datasets created from RDDs:

```
scala> val df_from_rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 5).toDF
df_from_rdd: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int]

scala> df_from_rdd.queryExecution.analyzed
res47: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#112]
+- ExternalRDD [obj#111]

scala> df_from_rdd.isLocal
res48: Boolean = false
```

Operations such as `Dataset.withColumn()` are actually executed by the driver itself as part of the lazy evaluation of the optimised query plan and never make it to the execution stage:

```
scala> val df_foo = df.withColumn("foo", functions.callUDF("myUdf", $"value"))
df_foo: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int, foo: string]

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.analyzed
res49: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
Project [value#107, UDF:myUdf(cast(value#107 as string)) AS foo#146]
+- LocalRelation [value#107]

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
java.lang.Exception
    at $line98.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.myUdf(<console>:25)
    at $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
    at $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.ConvertToLocalRelation$.apply(Optimizer.scala:1358)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.optimizedPlan(QueryExecution.scala:66)
    at $line143.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:27)
    ...
res50: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
LocalRelation [value#107, foo#132]
// Notice: the projection is gone, merged into the local relation

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
res51: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
LocalRelation [value#107, foo#163]
// Notice: no stack trace this time
```

unlike when dealing with a dataset created from an RDD:

```
scala> val df_from_rdd_foo = df_from_rdd.withColumn("foo", functions.callUDF("myUdf", $"value"))
df_from_rdd_foo: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [value: int, foo: string]

scala> df_from_rdd_foo.queryExecution.optimizedPlan
res52: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan =
Project [value#112, UDF:myUdf(cast(value#112 as string)) AS foo#135]
+- SerializeFromObject [input[0, int, false] AS value#112]
   +- ExternalRDD [obj#111]
```

which produces no stack trace in the executor's stderr, i.e., the UDF isn't called. On the other hand:

```
scala> df_from_rdd_foo.show()
+-----+---------+
|value|      foo|
+-----+---------+
|    0|0 changed|
|    1|1 changed|
|    2|2 changed|
|    3|3 changed|
|    4|4 changed|
|    5|5 changed|
+-----+---------+
```

produces the following stack trace in the executor's stderr:

```
java.lang.Exception
    at $line98.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.myUdf(<console>:25)
    at $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
    at $line99.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.project_doConsume_0$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    ...
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:409)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Spark treats local relations as literals, which can also be seen in the way they are represented in SQL (code adapted from [here](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-LogicalPlan-LocalRelation.html)):

```
scala> df.queryExecution.analyzed.collect { case r: LocalRelation => r }.head.toSQL("bar")
res55: String = VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) AS bar(value)

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.collect { case r: LocalRelation => r }.head.toSQL("bar")
res56: String = VALUES (0, '0 changed'), (1, '1 changed'), (2, '2 changed'), (3, '3 changed'), (4, '4 changed'), (5, '5 changed') AS bar(value, foo)
```

or alternatively as code:

```
scala> df.queryExecution.analyzed.asCode
res57: String = LocalRelation(
  List(value#107),
  Vector([0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5]),
  false
)

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.analyzed.asCode
res58: String = Project(
  List(value#107, UDF:myUdf(cast(value#107 as string)) AS foo#163),
  LocalRelation(
    List(value#107),
    Vector([0,0], [0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [0,4], [0,5]),
    false
  )
)

scala> df_foo.queryExecution.optimizedPlan.asCode
res59: String = LocalRelation(
  List(value#107, foo#163),
  Vector([0,0 changed], [1,1 changed], [2,2 changed], [3,3 changed], [4,4 changed], [5,5 changed]),
  false
)
```

Think of what's happening as the equivalent of your Java compiler replacing code such as `int a = 2 * 3;` with `int a = 6;` with the actual computation being done by the compiler.

Comment: thank you so much for this detailed explanation! After I refactored myUdf Method to a be ```public class MyUdf implements UDF1<String, String>, Serializable```, it could be executed on worker(s), depending on the value passed to ```repartition()```.

Comment: It should work fine once you start loading your data from files or database connections. For now, either keep shuffling with `repartition()` or base your test datasets off RDDs.