# Fitting LogisticRegression within a User Defined Fuction (UDF)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I've implemented the following code in Spark Scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification._

object Hello {
    def main(args: Array[String]) = {

          val getLabel1Probability = udf((param1: Double, labeledEntries: Seq[Array[Double]]) => {

            val trainingData = labeledEntries.map(entry => (org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(entry(0)), entry(1))).toList.toDF("features", "label")
            val regression = new LogisticRegression()
            val fittingModel = regression.fit(trainingData)

            val prediction = fittingModel.predictProbability(org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(param1))
            val probability = prediction.toArray(1)

            probability
          })

          val df = Seq((1.0, Seq(Array(1.0, 0), Array(2.0, 1))), (3.0, Seq(Array(1.0, 0), Array(2.0, 1)))).toDF("Param1", "LabeledEntries")

          val dfWithLabel1Probability = df.withColumn(
                "Label1Probability", getLabel1Probability(
                  $"Param1",
                  $"LabeledEntries"
                )
          )
          display(dfWithLabel1Probability)
    }
}

Hello.main(Array())
```

When running it on Databricks' notebook multi-node cluster (DBR (Databricks) 13.2, Spark 3.4.0 and Scala 2.12.), dfWithLabel1Probability's display gets shown.

I have the following questions:

- My understanding is that I should be getting a NullPointerException when creating the trainingData dataframe because [_sqlContext is null within the udf](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L244). If so, why am I not getting it? Is it related to running it from Databricks' notebook? Is the behaviour non-deterministic?
- If creating a dataframe is not allowed within a udf, how can I fit LogisticRegression with the data from a given dataframe's column? In the real example, I'm dealing with millions of rows for the dataframe so I would prefer avoiding the usage of `Dataset's collect()` to bring all those rows into driver's memory. Is there any alternative?

Thanks.

Comment: A duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61064044/why-in-cluster-mode-is-my-udf-executed-locally-in-driver-instead-on-worker

What happens in this case is that the UDF gets executed from the driver instead of from a worker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, if, instead, you run:

```scala
val largedf = spark.range(100000).selectExpr("cast(id as double) Param1", "array(array(1.0, 0), array(2.0, 1)) LabeledEntries")

val largedfWithLabel1Probability = largedf.withColumn(
    "Label1Probability", getLabel1Probability(
      $"Param1",
      $"LabeledEntries"
    )
)

display(largedfWithLabel1Probability)
```

it will npe, as will range of 1, but using:

```scala
(1 until 1000).map(a => (a.toDouble, Seq.. )).toDF..
```

it will start processing at least.  This is because toDF is using LocalRelation to build the data which is not sent to executors, whereas Range uses LeafNodes (executors) hence the exception.

re the second question that could be worth putting as a separate top level question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me clarify my question, the following code is part of a UDF "val trainingData = labeledEntries.map(entry => (org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors.dense(entry(0)), entry(1))).toList.toDF("features", "label")".

Should ".toDF("features", "label")" not throw a NullPointerException because it is trying to create a Dataset from an Executor?

Comment: It will IF the UDF run on an executor, the outer Dataset's execution decides that. Per my answer changing the outer df to run on the cluster causes the NPE, the same UDF is used in both cases.

Comment: Understood. I'm getting a "Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: $line7e65fba70aa34eee80dc6ade75e3aac844.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$Hello$" when running the first snippet you provided. Once I'm able to reproduce the NPE, I will accept this solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, remove the wrapping object Hello and main stuff it's not needed in notebooks.